# How many book pages would 891 words be?

Tags: formatting, book, wordcount, pages

I'm writing something and the font is Alegreya in 13 font size. So far I have 891 words and 4 pages. How many pages would that be in a book?

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, there's no single answer. This depends entirely on how the book is designed, laid out, and typeset. Every book published or printed needs to decide things like font, font size, margins, spacing, and a bunch of other factors, that meant there's no easy answer of "N pages precisely." Is there a particular reason you want the (estimated) page count?

Comment: ... other factors that massively influence the length of book versus the numbers of words it contains includes average length of paragraphs, how much dialogue there is (as dialog tends to produce lots of short lines that don't have many words on them), number of chapters (as chapters often have blank or half blank pages associated), etc.

Comment: Why do you want to know? If it's too know when you've written enough for your purposes, it would be wiser to research word counts. For example, novels are 50,000 words or more.

Comment: @J.G. 50k words is generally too short for a novel. More common is in between 80k and 100k. Source: http://www.writersdigest.com/editor-blogs/guide-to-literary-agents/word-count-for-novels-and-childrens-books-the-definitive-post

Comment: @TotumusMaximus Very true. There's a lot to say about optimum novel length depending on whether it's your debut, if it's part of a series, genre, techniques etc., more than I thought a comment could deal with. That's why I focused on the definitional minimum instead.

Answer (score 10):

There is no single answer that can be given for this, since books can be typeset in a variety of different ways, and different font faces and sizes will produce a varying number of words per page.

However, a generally accepted [formatting](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/24/) for manuscripts is double-spaced, 12-point Times New Roman, with one-inch page margins. Based on that, it's assumed that one page will be approximately 250 words.

Here are some online "calculators" I found that will let you adjust the font face, size, and number of words in order to produce a page count estimate:

[WordCounter](https://wordcounter.net/words-per-page)
[Convert Words to Pages](http://www.wordstopages.com/)
[Word Count to Page Count](https://essayscam.org/word-page-count-calculator/)
[Words to Page Converter](https://writingpeak.co.uk/words-to-page-converter)

Comment: Although manuscript format rarely works out the same as printed book format, manuscript format is 250 words per page *if the page is completely full*, i.e. it's a single paragraph of text with no added spacing.  Some publishers prefer to work with an estimated word count based on 250 words per page (or similar if using a different format) rather than the actual word count, because it makes it easier to estimate the number of pages in the final book (which varies acording to format but is likely to be somewhere in the range of 0.5-0.75 * number of manuscript pages).

Comment: (Although, manuscript format uses *Courier* not *Times*)

Comment: @Jules Courier used to be the standard font, but Times New Roman has now become more commonly requested. Arial is another possibility.

Comment: @Jules I believe it's Courier for *screenplays*, which have very strict rules, and require a fixed width font. In my experience, book manuscript expectations are much less strict, but Times New Roman is indeed the standard.

Comment: Maybe true (although I still see a lot of references suggesting Courier), but the 250 words per page count is definitely based on using Courier, which is much wider per character than Times.  I'd expect 300-350 words on a page using Times.

Comment: @Jules I added a few "page count calculators" that I found to my answer.

Comment: I though we used 11 point these days rather than 12 point?

Answer (score 1):

Common mass market paperbacks are generally 250-300 words per page.  Trade paperbacks typically run a similar count, due to larger type and wider margins.  Hardbacks and trade paperbacks are printed from the same plates, most times, so word counts will be the same.

That said, this is variable.  Occasionally, a publisher will reduce type size by a point to cut nearly a hundred pages from a very long novel, and this might push the word count on a page to as much as 350; other times, they'll bump type size up a point to "fill out" a short work, dropping the word count per page as low as 200 words.  Neither of these practices are as common in this day of electronic typesetting as they were, say, in the 1970s, in part because there are other ways to accomplish the same ends, and in part because the physical thickness of a book on the shelf at the bookstore matters less than it did (in large part because most books sold today aren't on paper at all).